# Need Feedback : Credit (Pset1- CS50x)

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    long int number;
    int count = 0;  // starting the count counter
    do {
        number = get_long("Please enter your 13-16 digit credit card number: \n"); //getting input from the user
    } while (number <= 0);

    int d1 = number % 10;                                           //separating digit number 1
    int d2 = ((number % 100) / 10);                                 //separating digit number 2
    int d3 = ((number % 1000) / 100);                               //separating digit number 3
    int d4 = ((number % 10000) / 1000);                             //separating digit number 4
    int d5 = ((number % 100000) / 10000);                           //separating digit number 5
    int d6 = ((number % 1000000) / 100000);                         //separating digit number 6
    int d7 = ((number % 10000000) / 1000000);                       //separating digit number 7
    int d8 = ((number % 100000000) / 10000000);                     //separating digit number 8
    int d9 = ((number % 1000000000) / 100000000);                   //separating digit number 9
    int d10 = ((number % 10000000000) / 1000000000);                //separating digit number 10
    int d11 = ((number % 100000000000) / 10000000000);              //separating digit number 11
    int d12 = ((number % 1000000000000) / 100000000000);            //separating digit number 12
    int d13 = ((number % 10000000000000) / 1000000000000);          //separating digit number 13
    int d14 = ((number % 100000000000000) / 10000000000000);        //separating digit number 14
    int d15 = ((number % 1000000000000000) / 100000000000000);      //separating digit number 15
    int d16 = ((number % 10000000000000000) / 1000000000000000);    //separating digit number 16
    int last13 = number / 1000000000000;        //finding the last one digit of 13 digit VISA
    int last15 = number / 10000000000000;       //finding the last two digit of 15 digit AMEX
    int last16v = number / 1000000000000000;    //finding the last one digit of 16 digit VISA
    int last16m = number / 100000000000000;     //finding the last two digit of 16 digit MASTERCARD
    int a2 = (d2 * 2);
    int a4 = (d4 * 2);
    int a6 = (d6 * 2);
    int a8 = (d8 * 2);
    int a10 = (d10 * 2);
    int a12 = (d12 * 2);
    int a14 = (d14 * 2);
    int a16 = (d16 * 2);
    if (a2 >= 10) {             // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a11a = (a2 % 100) / 10;
        int a12a = (a2 % 10);
        a2 = a11a + a12a;
    }
    if (a4 >= 10) {           // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a31 = (a4 % 100)  / 10;
        int a32 = (a4 % 10);
        a4 = a31 + a32;
    }
    if (a6 >= 10) {             // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a51 = (a6 % 100) / 10;
        int a52 = (a6 % 10);
        a6 = a51 + a52;
    }
    if (a8 >= 10) {              // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a71 = (a8 % 100) / 10;
        int a72 = (a8 % 10);
        a8 = a71 + a72;
    }
    if (a10 >= 10) {        // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a91 = (a10 % 100) / 10;
        int a92 = (a10 % 10);
        a10 = a91 + a92;
    }
    if (a12 >= 10) {              // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a111 = (a12 % 100) / 10;
        int a112 = (a12 % 10);
        a12 = a111 + a112;
    }
    if (a14 >= 10) {               // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a131 = (a14 % 100) / 10;
        int a132 = (a14 % 10);
        a14 = a131 + a132;
    }
    if (a16 >= 10) {              // separating the digits of the multiple
        int a151 = (a16 % 100) / 10;
        int a152 = (a16 % 10);
        a16 = a151 + a152;
    }
    int b = d1 + d3 + d5 + d7 + d9 + d11 + d13 + d15;
    int c = a2 + a4 + a6 + a8 + a10 + a12 + a14 + a16;
    int l = b + c;
    int j = a2 + a4 + a6 + a8 + a10 + a12;
    int k =  d1 + d3 + d5 + d7 + d9 + d11 + d13;
    int m = j + k;
    int e = d1 + d3 + d5 + d7 + d9 + d11 + d13 + d15;
    int x = a2 + a4 + a6 + a8 + a10 + a12 + a14;
    int n = x + e;
    printf("%i", n);
    if (l % 10 == 0) {                     //checking if the checksum is valid
        for (int i = number; number != 0; i++) {   // counting the credit card number
            number /= 10;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 16) {
            if (last16m == 51) {             // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");   // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else
            if (last16m == 52) {       // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");   // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else
            if (last16m == 53) {        // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");     // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else
            if (last16m == 54) {            // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");          //// printing the result based on last two digits
            } else
            if (last16m == 55) {               // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");         // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else
            if (last16v == 4) {                // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("VISA\n");              // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
            if (count != 16) {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }

    if (m % 10 == 0) {                    //checking if the checksum is valid
        for (int i = number; number != 0; i++) {       // counting the credit card number
            number /= 10;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 13) {
            if (last13 == 4) {   // checking the last one digit of credit card
                printf("VISA\n");       // printing the result based on last one digit
            } else {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
    if (n % 10 == 0) {                  //checking if the checksum is valid
        for (int i = number; number != 0; i++) {        // counting the credit card number
            number /= 10;
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 15) {
            if (last15 == 34) {     // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("AMEX\n");         // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else
            if (last15 == 37) {      // checking the last two digit of credit card
                printf("AMEX\n");        // printing the result based on last two digits
            } else {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }

            if (count != 15) {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using `4003600000000014` and it gives the correct output. Taking `4222222222222`, it returns `INVALID`. It also doesn't works for AMEX numbers (15 digits). It doesn't responds on giving `4111111111111113` as input (it should return `0`). Please tell me what's wrong, I am a newbie to programming. This is the result it gives on checking it through check50 https://submit.cs50.io/check50/44370b403c33f9b47d462e3278458901599d16e1.

Comment: You want to use `unsigned long long` which can have [effectively] 18 digits. But, I think you need to understand arrays as your code is replicating the functionality of an array with scalars. Instead of (e.g.) `int d1,d2,d3,d4`, you want to use `int d[4];` Also, because the card can be 16 digits long, most people doing this problem use an array of `char` to store the card and manipulate it using BCD (binary coded decimal). See: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/33002/cs50-pset1-credit And, note that link goes to an entire group devoted to `cs50`, so that may be a better place to ask

Comment: Okay right off the bat I'm seeing an absolutely absurd number of variables, so until you learn about arrays you're going to be stuck going in the completely wrong direction.

Comment: Secondly, please help us out and **delete extra blank lines** which serve absolutely no purpose other than to make seeing all your code more difficult due to scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the type for `number` should be `unsigned long long` to ensure it is large enough to handle the 16 digits. `unsigned long` may be large enough on some platforms, such as 64-bit linux and OS/X, but not on others such as all versions of Windows.
- the computations are lengthy and cumbersome, it would be much more readable to use an array of digit values.
- it is unclear whether you compute the `count` of digits once or multiple times. The loop modifies `number` and does not initialize `count` explicitly (and the variable `i` is useless). If run multiple times, it works by coincidence as `number` will already be `0` from the first run. You should use a temporary variable with the proper type and compute `count` just once.
- the tests for different card number lengths may have false positives: for example if `m % 10 == 0` and the card number does not have 13 digits, you would print `INVALID` incorrectly. The test should be first on the number of digits, then on the checksum.
- it is very confusing to refer to the initial digits as *the last digits*.

Here is a simpler version using an array:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// emulate cs50 get_long_long()
static long long get_long_long(const char *prompt) {
    for (;;) {
        long long n;
        int c;

        printf("%s", prompt);
        if (scanf("%llu", &n) == 1)
            return n;
        printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
        // flush the rest of the input line
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (c == EOF)
            exit(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    long long int number, num;
    int digit[16] = { 0 };
    int count;
    for (;;) {        //getting input from the user
        number = get_long_long("Please enter your 13-16 digit credit card number: \n");
        if (number > 0)
            break;
    }
    // only accept numbers with 13 to 16 digits
    if (number < 1000000000000 || number > 9999999999999999) {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (count = 0, num = number; num != 0; count++) {
        digit[count] = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    // compute checksum
    int checksum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 2) {
        int a1 = digit[i];
        int a2 = digit[i + 1] * 2;
        if (a2 >= 10)
            a2 -= 9;
        checksum += a1 + a2;
    }        
    //printf("checksum: %d, ", checksum);

    int first = digit[count - 1];
    int first2 = 10 * digit[count - 1] + digit[count - 2];

    if (checksum % 10 == 0) {
        if (count == 16) {
            if (first2 >= 51 && first2 <= 55) {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
                return 0;
            } else
            if (first == 4) {
                printf("VISA\n");
                return 0;
            }
        } else
        if (count == 13) {
            if (first == 4) {
                printf("VISA\n");
                return 0;
            }
        } else
        if (count == 15) {
            if (first2 == 34 || first2 == 37) {
                printf("AMEX\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("INVALID\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, my code worked after I decided to count the number first and then in second step check the number of digits, and then finally checking the checksum. And thank you again for suggesting long long unsigned.